# What are some alternate methods of communication with aircraft (specifically small drones)?

Tags: radio-communications, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, radio

I've been thinking about his alot but I've yet to find an answer.

Most of the time drones use radio, wi-fi, GPS and Bluetooth signals to communicate with their controllers but all of these methods can easily be intercepted, espically radio signals.

Are there any alternate methods of communicating with drones and of there isn't, what are some ways to make it harder for other people to jam or intercept the signals?

Thanks.

Comment: _'I've yet to find an answer'_ - there isn't a single answer. Even your question asks for _'some ways'_. This is way too broad for a concise answer. Trying narrowing the focus to something more specific.

Comment: Wired communication, e.g. copper wire or fiber optics, are pretty much impossible to jam or intercept. Directional wireless communication, e.g. mmW or laser beams are also good choices. Radio can be made very robust, too. Wifi, 4G and Bluetooth are easy to jam because they are industrial standards that operates at known frequencies. In the military context, where the majority of concern for jamming occurs, doesn't have to follow industry standard or FCC/ITU regulations and operates at a much wider frequency range, hence hard to jam as well.

Comment: @user3528438 to your point, tethered drones do exist (e.g. mobile cell tower ) .

Comment: Interception is only a problem for unsecured communication.

Comment: I really don't like that question being answered.

Comment: You really seem to be starting from a position of extreme ignorance.  Wi-Fi and Bluetooth ARE radio signals, occupying particular parts of the frequency spectrum (and with modulation & encoding specifications).  GPS signals are likewise radio, but they are receive-only, so not really communication.  The only other halfway practical way I can think of would be to modulate the signal of a laser pointer, but that would require line of site and some pretty accurate pointing on your part.   And why would I jam when I have a shotgun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interception is not a concern when the communications are strongly encrypted.

Plaintext (unencrypted) communications are obsolete for all except for the most public purposes. The search request that led you to this site was encrypted. The page you're currently reading is encrypted, in a way that would take effort even for the NSA to crack, even though everything on this page is openly available to anyone in the world.

Wi-fi and bluetooth are subtypes of radio, and too short-range for a flying drone. GPS is actually effectively impossible to intercept, as it's all public and there's nothing *to* intercept.

Regardless, [encryption](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) takes care of the contents of your communications.

If you want to hide the very fact that communication is taking place, laser links are the only option that isn't easily detected through dispersion, sidelobes and reflections. High-frequency traders use laser links commercially up to [about 10 km](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/176551-new-laser-network-between-nyse-and-nasdaq-will-allow-high-frequency-traders-to-make-even-more-money). This is reliable all-weather ground to ground range. Ground-to-air comms have been tested for [up to 60 km on a clear day](https://www.japcc.org/optical-data-links-aerial-applications-promising-technology-future-rpa-operations/).

Fighter aircraft communicate with their jamming/decoy drones through a copper or fiber optics cable, which is also used as a tension cable for towing.